# how to define <element-collection> for a List<String> field?

Tags: orm, mapping, persistence, jpa-2.0

If my object has a

```
protected List<String> fileNote;
```

What is the right way to define that relationship in an orm.xml?

(note: I do *not* want to use annotations.)

Comment: Which ORM framework are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry; I'm using JPA 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple, if you are satisfied with defaults is:

```
<element-collection name="fileNote"/>
```

If more customization is needed, you can go further:

```
<element-collection name="fileNote" fetch="EAGER" access="FIELD/>
  <column name="some_name_for_column_that_holds_note" />
  <collection-table name="descriptive_name_for_table">
    <join-column name="some_id" />
  </collection-table>
</element-collection/>
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I was struggling so much with that.

Comment: I get this error `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "element-collection" must be declared.` any idea?