# Persist List<String> or Set<String> without anotations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

using anotation should be something like

```
public class User {
    private int userId;
    ...
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> countries = new HashSet<String>();
```

but I need to map it on a xml file. I try:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.foo.User" table="user">
    ...
    <property name="userId" />
    ...
            <set name="countries" table="user_country">
                <key column="userId" />
                <element type="string" column="country" />
            </set>
    ...
```

the table user_country have userId (foreign key) and country that is a varchar

Comment: Do you mean, u want to get <set> ... <set> to be an element of your countires?

Comment: if you only want the name of the countries, then can't you use some parser to retrieve the name?

Comment: Set with list-index? A varchar country? And what is the question?

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808975/how-to-define-element-collection-for-a-liststring-field to know how to map a List<String> in xml mapping way.

Comment: @nafas I did't understand what you say.

Comment: @laune sorry I copy it from a list, I want to configure the user.hbm.xml file to have a list of Strings

Comment: @xedo what is that you want to store in your "Set<String> countries"

Comment: @user3487063 how can I refer it?

Comment: @xedo  i know its some "sort" of string. but what sort of strings, is it some XML tags or some stuff from within the XML file